# How do I apply Bayes Theorem here?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, bayes-theorem

Given [this table that shows the relationship between discounts on houses and condos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un3SA.png) and knowing that the supply distribution is 83% and 17% for houses and condos respectively I have to compute the probability that a home for sale is a house *and* that there have been given a 10% or greater discount.

So far, I have defined two events:

The probability that a home is a house P(B1) = 0.83 & the probability that a home is a condo P(B2)= 0.17.

I tried using the Multiplication Rule solve my problem:

0.12 * 0.83 = 9.96%

I am not sure this is correct, though, since I am having a hard time interpreting the information from the table.

Next question is: What is the probability that any given home was discounted more than 10%? I am completely lost here ...

Comment: No Bayes' here.  Your approach looks good.

Comment: If the probability you are supposed to compute assumes that someone has selected a home at random from the set of all homes for sale, where each home had an equal chance to be selected, and without receiving any further information you want the probability that the selected home is a house that has been discounted more than 10%, I agree your calculation is a correct application of the rules for conditional probabilities. Do you want to understand how to explain it better?

Comment: Yeah ... My intuition for Bayes' Theorem is a bit rusty and now I am stuck on the next problem. How would you compute the probability that any given home was discounted more than 10%? That's where it gets really tough.

Comment: Still no Bayes', even for the second question.  To help with intuition, suppose there are $N$ homes in the universe.  Now...use the data to count the number of houses, condos, discounted houses, discounted condos.

Comment: Bayes' comes up in inference style problems.  "a randomly selected home has a discount of $15\%$.  What is the probability that it is a condo?"

Answer (score 1):

You have done the right arithmetic so far, so I'll concentrate on
the language and the notation for conditional probability,
which seems to be causing some difficulty.

You have the table
\begin{array}{cccc}
\rlap{\text{discount on a house}} \\
\text{none} & 0\% \text{ to }10\% & > 10\% \\
63\% & 25\% & 12\%
\end{array}

The numbers in the bottom row add up to $100\%$, so it seems safe to 
assume that if you randomly pick a *house* that is for sale,
there is a $12\%$ chance it is discounted more than $10\%$.

If you randomly pick *any* home, and then ask whether it is a house
and the answer turns out to be "yes," then you can use the fact that you
know this is a house to estimate the probability of a discount.
That is, we again say there is a $12\%$ chance that the home is discounted more than $10\%$.

In the language of conditional probability,

> The probability a home for sale is discounted more than $10\%$, given that the home is a house, is $12\%$.

To write this in mathematical notation, if $B_1$ is the event that the
randomly selected home is a house and
$D_{10}$ is the event that the randomly selected home
is discounted more than $10\%$, then
$P(D_{10} \mid B_1)$ is the probability a home for sale is discounted more than $10\%$ given that the home is a house,
and we can write
$$
P(D_{10} \mid B_1) = 0.12.
$$

Now there is a rule for conditional probability that
$$
P(A \text{ and } B) = P(A \mid B) \cdot P(B).
$$

The application of this rule to your question is that
$$
P(D_{10} \text{ and } B_1) = P(D_{10} \mid B) \cdot P(B)
= 0.12 \cdot 0.83 = 0.0996,
$$
which means that the probability a home for sale is discounted more
than $10\%$ *and* is a house is $9.96\%$.

Now if you want the probability that a random home is discounted more than
$10\%$, that is, you want $P(D_{10})$, since we already know every home for sale is either a house or a condo, the event $(B_1 \text{ or } B_2)$
is always true, and
$$
D_{10} = D_{10} \text{ and } (B_1 \text{ or } B_2)
= (D_{10} \text{ and } B_1) \text{ or } (D_{10} \text{ and } B_2).
$$
That is, a home is discounted more that $10\%$ if and only if
the home is discounted more that $10\%$ and is a house or
the home is discounted more that $10\%$ and is a condo.
Therefore
$$
P(D_{10}) = 
P((D_{10} \text{ and } B_1) \text{ or } (D_{10} \text{ and } B_2)).
$$

Is it clear that the event $(D_{10} \text{ and } B_1)$ and the
event $(D_{10} \text{ and } B_2)$ are two mutually exclusive events
(that is, they cannot both happen)?
Then we can find the probability $P(D_{10})$ in terms of things
we already know how to compute, such as $P(D_{10} \text{ and } B_1)$.

Comment: I really appreciate the answer! Super helpful. I am having a tough time figuring out the way to arithmetically compute P(D10)=P((D10 and B1) or (D10 and B2)), though.

Comment: I suppose I can just add them?

Comment: Yes, because the two events are disjoint (mutually exclusive). If $A$ and $B$ cannot happen simultaneously, then $P(A\text{ or }B) = P(A) + P(B)$.